# How to redirect output of cu to a file ?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using cu utility to connect my Cubieboard 1 with my laptop. As I boot my Cubieboard , it sends the boot log to my terminal.

What I want is that the output should be displayed to my screen as well as be sent to some log file which I specify.

I can't find any option to do the same. Any ideas on how I could do that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if standard error should be in the file

```
<command> 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

or

```
<command> |& log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe into tee. You should then see output on screen and logged to a file of your choice.

```
<command> | tee log.txt
```